# Windows 10 crashes while in hibernation or sleep mode

Tags: windows-10, crash, sleep, shutdown, hibernate

Recently when I put my intel i5-9400f PC into hibernation or sleep mode, it enters that mode for some time then it crashes.

Crashes as in the next time I boot up the PC I get messages from the programs I left open that the PC has shut down incorrectly as if I pulled the power cable while the PC is running.

I searched for a solution for this issue for so long and applied multiple different troubleshooting such as editing the power plan to specific settings, disabling fast boot, etc... but sadly nothing really fixed it.

Comment: If you see `.dmp` crash files in `C:\Windows\Minidump`, zip up a few and post them online for examination (Dropbox, OneDrive etc).

Answer (score 1):

Turn OFF Hybrid Sleep in Advanced Power Settings. Then turn OFF Hibernation. Hibernation sometime causes issues on some machines and I like Sleep much better, so I turn the machine OFF (use Fast Start) instead of using Hibernate.

Restart, and try just Sleep. That should work as just Sleep tends to work better. I have used just Sleep for years with no issues.

Be sure BIOS and Power Drivers are both up to date.

Comment: For multiple reasons including having to open multiple documents, programs and web pages, even with Fast Start shutting down and opening the PC each time I need to use it isn't ideal for me, I usually need to get back exactly where I left off. As for using sleep instead, well I rarely use that as where I'm living at the moment power outages happen from time to time, thus hibernation is my best option here. Nonetheless, I'll follow the steps you mentioned and report back.

Comment: Sleep allows you to very quickly get back precisely to where you left off and works really well. I have left my computer sleeping overnight with no huge battery drain.  This is preferable to having the machine crash via hibernation.

Comment: @John, though you may have had Hibernation issues on a particular machine, I've used hibernation for *many* Windows PC's without issue for many years. Unlike Sleep, Hibernation does not continuously drain the battery, is is safer for laptops and for desktops having no UPS, in areas with frequent outages. That said, if dual-booting, be sure the hibernated Windows partition is **read-only**, since any writing to that partition will cause issues when rebooting Windows. Also, disable Fast Startup in Windows and Quick Boot in BIOS for dual-boot OS machines.

Comment: Hibernation works on some machines and not others and Sleep has never been an issue for me. If Hibernation works (it does not in this case) then, of course use it.